# Cabal does not found package installed rpm package

Tags: cabal

I try to install gf-core from https://github.com/GrammaticalFramework/gf-core to an RHEL 9 having Cabal installed with `yum instal`. `gf.cabal` says `utf8-string >= 1.0.1.1 && < 1.1` and `rpm -q -l ghc-utf8-string` shows the file /usr/lib64/libHSutf8-string-1.0.2-8YAqI3SiGe8GKwxImEgLZR-ghc8.10.7.so. Doing cabal install says

```
[__1] unknown package: utf8-string (dependency of gf)
```

So is there something wrong with search path or something? A known bug?